# Custom layout using layer-list xml not exactly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layer-list

I custom my layout by using layer-list xml in Android. But, I done for layer-list and see exactly what i want to custom. But, when I apply in my layout, it show not exactly what i want, I don't know why.Help me, please!
This is my layer-list.xml:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size
            android:width="@dimen/dp35"
            android:height="@dimen/dp35" />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:right="12dp"
    android:top="@dimen/dp20"
    android:bottom="-5dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="25">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
<item android:left="12.5dp"
    android:top="@dimen/dp20"
    android:bottom="-5dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-25">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

[Preview 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GMzb.png)

My layout using layer-list.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_sale_off"
        android:text="Textview"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[Preview 2 ( without triangle at bottom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLOFM.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_sale_off"
        android:text="Textview"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```